# How can I exclude a view from the API documentation?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I use django-rest-framework (DRF) to provide the REST API of a site of mine. From what I understand, the automatic generation of API documentation relies on DRF's generation of a [schema](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/). It may then be interpreted by a third-party tool to produce pretty documentation. I've used `django-rest-swagger` as the tool that produces the pretty documentation from DRF's schema, but I suspect the solution to my problem is DRF-based, independent of whatever tool I use to transform the schema to something "pretty".

The problem is that by default, DRF provides documentation for the whole API, even though some parts of it are really for my sites own internal purpose. **I'd like some views to be excluded from the documentation.** Some views should always be excluded. Some views should be excluded only if the user viewing the documentation is not logged into the site.

Answer (score 13):

This isn't well documented. On a class-based view, you can set the `exclude_from_schema` attribute to `True` to exclude the view from the documentation. Example:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, mixins
class SomeViewSet(mixins...., viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    exclude_from_schema = True

    [...]
```

If you search the current documentation for `exclude_from_schema` you'll find a hit [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view), which documents the presence of a parameter for the `@api_view` decorator, which has for effect of setting the attribute as shown above. The attribute itself though is currently not mentioned in DRF's documentation.

If you want to exclude a view **based on a condition**, you can use the `@property` decorator so that `exclude_from_schema` becomes a computed attribute. Behind the scenes, when DRF needs to produce the schema for the view, it will instantiate the class with the `Request` object that was generated when the user browsed to the documentation page. So you can test to check whether the user that is accessing the documentation was authenticated or not:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, mixins, permissions
class SomeViewSet(mixins...., viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    @property
    def exclude_from_schema(self):
        return not permissions.IsAuthenticated().has_permission(self.request,
                                                                self)

    [...]
```

`self.request` is the `Request` object that was generated when the user asked for the documentation. We use one of the classes provided by `rest_framework.permissions` directly because the code that generates the schema does not use the `permission_classes` attribute that may be set on `SomeViewSet`.

Comment: `exclude_from_schema` is deprecated. Should use `schema=None` and `@schema(None)` for function based views.

Comment: Isn't it possible to exclude endpoints based on API prefix?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer because it's not well documented in DRF ([although it was made as an announcement](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.9-announcement/)):

> ### `exclude_from_schema`
>
> Both `APIView.exclude_from_schema` and the `exclude_from_schema` argument to the `@api_view` have now been removed.
>
> For `APIView` [class-based] you should instead set a `schema = None` attribute on the view class.
>
> For function-based views the `@schema` decorator can be used to exclude the view from the schema, by using `@schema(None)`.